# How to avoid overlap between main window created by Electron and other window that are not managed by Electrion?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, desktop-application

### Background

- I am quite new with Election
- I would like to create a sticky note desktop application like [google desktop](https://google-desktop.en.softonic.com/)
- My expectation is that the other window (In this case, notepad) should not overlap with main window created by election as attached.
  [In case of Google desktop-min.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2cZv.png)

### Issue

- In my electron applicaiton, the other window (In this case, notepad) overlaps with main window created by election as attached.
  [In case of my electron app-min.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRhuf.png)

Here is my code. I set `alwaysOnTop: true` to make the main window to always to be on top.
However, it seems it is not sufficient.

```
function createWindow() {

  const { width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight } = screen.getPrimaryDisplay().size;

  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 300,
    height: screenHeight, // Set the height to match the screen height
    x: screenWidth - 300 + 1, // Position the window on the right side
    y: 0,
    movable: false,       // Prevent window from being moved
    minimizable: false,   // Prevent window from being minimized
    maximizable: false,   // Prevent window from being maximized
    alwaysOnTop: true,
    autoHideMenuBar: true, // Hide the menu bar
    frame: false,        // Create a frameless window
    // transparent: true,   // Make the window transparent
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  });

  // Load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html');

  // Open DevTools when the app starts
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
}
```